# Why is it considered that a set unnormalizes a database absolutely?

Tags: normalization, relational-theory

In order for a relationship to be on 1NF it needs to have all values as atomic, if there's a set it's not even in that first normal form:

But intuitively I think that a table with that set would be more normalized than one that is not as long as the values of that set are just used as attributes of the entity.

For example, let's imagine this table about paintings:

Painting_name, Author, Used technique, Used colors

Now if we get to use a set of colors like {blue, Green, yellow, black, White, purple} we get a table that is not even in 1NF.

If we pass the table to 1NF, then we need to have 6 rows each one repeating the Painting_name, Author, and Used technique.

This looks way more unnormalized than the table that is not even in 1NF, and I don't see why having a set there would harm any possible normalization, as that sets would only be used in that table.

What is then the reason that atomic values are needed in order to have a normalized table?

Comment: Related Q & A: [Is sql_variant compatible with First Normal Form (1NF)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/213421/1192) and [First Normal Form: Definitive Definition](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/161119/1192)

Comment: ["1NF" has many meanings.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40640962/3404097)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reference for this post is an amazing book called [Database System Concepts 6th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073523321) which I recommend you read.

In the book, page 328, it states:

> A domain is atomic if elements of the domain are considered to be indivisible units. We say that a relation schema R is in first normal form (1NF) if
>   the domains of all attributes of R are atomic.

You might be wondering "but why!?", it's best explained using a practical example.

Let's look at your example with colors. Lets say we have 2 scenarios, 1.) where the table is **not** in 1NF, 2.) where the table is in 1NF.

1.)

```
Id          Painting_name                  Author                         Used_colors
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------
1           Some_Painting                  John                           Blue, red, Yellow
2           Monalisa                       Leonardo da Vinci              orange, black, White, red, Yellow
```

Although this might seem intuitive to you, consider what happens when you want to query this table. One, you have inconsistent upper and lower case (which you would have to check with your query for both cases) two, if `used_colors` isn't an array, you would either have to convert it to an array or use extra steps just to check the data you need (like using a `string_split` function in SQL Server 2014 and later).

This causes performance issues and ends up being a hassle every time you want to check for something. If you are wondering what stops a person from typing in `black_white_yellow` instead? That question is answered in 2NF and 3NF, foreign key constraints etc...

2.)

```
Id          Painting_name                  Author                         Used_colors
----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------------
3           Some_Painting                  John                           Blue
4           Some_Painting                  John                           red
5           Some_Painting                  John                           Yellow
6           Monalisa                       Leonardo da Vinci              orange
7           Monalisa                       Leonardo da Vinci              black
8           Monalisa                       Leonardo da Vinci              White
9           Monalisa                       Leonardo da Vinci              red
10          Monalisa                       Leonardo da Vinci              Yellow
```

In this case, every single row is atomic and unique. What did we gain by doing this? You don't have to think about handling arrays, since every single row now is atomic you can clearly check for what you need quickly and efficiently.

And just to give you an idea of how big of a hassle it could become, here are some posts related to the issue of searching for values in a comma separated column:

- [How can I check whether a number is contained in a comma separated
  list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33278789/how-can-i-check-whether-a-number-is-contained-in-comma-separated-list-stored-in)
- [Using Comma Separated String Value in a Select Statement](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f95becd-995c-4973-84dc-92ff71d6e418/using-comma-separated-string-value-in-a-select-statement?forum=transactsql)

There are also many different approaches, none of which are really elegant to say the least (at least pertaining to the problem of 1NF). So, basically by using the 1NF you go from using code like the ones mentioned in those posts above to simple stuff like:

```
SELECT * FROM Paintings WHERE Used_colors LIKE 'BLUE'
```

Which helps in both readability and performance.

There is one thing you need to keep in mind, 1NF is only the starting point of the normalization process. The 1NF alone is practically never used in any DB out there, after the 1NF comes the 2NF where you would have to split this table into two separate tables. `Used_colors` will be made into its own table called `Colors`. At this point you will reach the cardinality issue which is also covered in the book mentioned above.

One last thing, there are many cases where you're going to come across databases that break the 1NF on one or more tables while adhering to the rules of 2NF, 3NF and even 4NF. For example [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) has `json` data type which immediately breaks the 1NF rule (as you can save multiple keys and values in json). The general rule of thumb goes like this: Always follow the normal forms unless you really know what you're doing. Since the moment you introduce such variables you could cause inconsistencies throughout the database and you will most likely lose on performance.

Also, as Paul said in the comment below, there is another point of view which Christopher. J. Date supports(who is a famous researcher and writer on relational DB theory as well as being one of the people with Ted Codd who helped push the relational model). This outlook stabs at the idea of atomic values in 1NF, saying that the whole term "atomic" is ambiguous. The idea behind this is simple, you can say that almost no data type is atomic under the current definition of 1NF. To explain this, lets take a look at an example:

Lets say you have a string `Hello World`. You have functions in every DBMS that decomposes this string into smaller chunks (like the `SUBSTRING` or `LEFT` / `RIGHT` functions) which means that `string` isn't really an atomic value as everything can be decomposed. This outlook is similar to data types such as `json`, you can decompose both string and json, so why is one considered atomic while the other not? That's why C. J. Date considers the current definition of 1NF as ambiguous, since almost all data types can be decomposed in one way or another. If you access `json` or `xml` data types as a whole unit without decomposing them, there is nothing to say that `json` or `xml` data type isn't atomic.

You can find an interesting paper on [The Third Manifesto](http://www.thethirdmanifesto.com/), they (C. J. Date and Hugh Darwin) made their paper on [Databases, Types and the Relational Model The Third Manifesto](https://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/DTATRM.pdf) publicly available. It's also an interesting read which will send you to interesting other articles and topics in general.

Answer (score 2):

“Normalized” just means the the model follows a standard convention for Relational Databases.  It doesn’t mean that it’s better or worse.

It’s simply the definition of what a Relational Database is that multi-valued attributes are not allowed in a “normalized” schema.

Many useful data modeling techniques allow arrays as attributes, and where the guidelines of how to do relational modeling correctly can be ignored.

And in practice it’s reasonably common to store a few non-scalar attributes (typically in XML or JSON) in a relational schema that is otherwise normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Atomic Values: It means a single value, not containing a delimiter (like comma) separated multiple values in single rows. That's why {blue, Green, yellow, black, White, purple} in a single row is not atomic. Therefore it is not in 1NF.

If you keep non atomic value like {blue, Green, yellow, black, White, purple} in single rows then technically you will face many problems. Even if you get any solution, then that will be very very cumbersome and far less performant.

Efficiency, performance are very important factors in the database world (in other worlds also).

If you have one to many relation then you have to create separate Mapping table.

```
Painting_Color_Mapping
-----------------------
PaintingID
Colorid
```

Answer (score -1):

> If we pass the table to 1NF, then we need to have 6 rows each one repeating the Painting_name, Author, and Used technique.

No, you can also add a `Painting_ID`, that whay  the tables that refer to a painting can use this to reference the painting.

Likewise you should not store `Author`, but `Author_ID`. If the name of this author changes (because you made a typo), you will only have to change 1 record (in the Authors-table). Aslo if you want to add more info about this author, like i.e. birthdate than every painting by this author will have this info too.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was refering all the time only to the same table. Painting id makes sense only if there's other table to relate to, which I wasn' consideringt.